# ManyToMany Relationships with Doctrine's QueryBuilder and Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

On a site I'm working on I need to limit results in quite a few places based on a setting for a user. This is a member on the user called Counties, and is an entity in it's own right. I have it set up like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="county")
 */
class County
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $name;

    // ... Getters and Setters
}
```

On my User entity, I have it attached like this:

```
// ...

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\County")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_county_xref",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="county_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $counties;

// ...

/**
 * Add counties
 *
 * @param \App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\County $counties
 * @return User
 */
public function addCountie(\App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\County $counties)
{
    $this->counties[] = $counties;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove counties
 *
 * @param \App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\County $counties
 */
public function removeCountie(\App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\County $counties)
{
    $this->counties->removeElement($counties);
}

/**
 * Get counties
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getCounties()
{
    return $this->counties;
}
```

That all works like it should, and I can attach counties to Users without an issue.

I then have a second entity called Store which also has these County entities attached to it. I did the same declaration but changed the `JoinTable` name to something different and changed the `JoinColumn` to use `store_id` instead of `user_id`. By itself, this works just fine. I can attach counties to stores.

Now, what I want to do is limit the counties based on the user's counties. For example, if the user is in County A and County B, I only want to see the stores in County A and County B.

I cannot figure out how to do that using DQL or the Query Builder. This makes matters worse when I'm trying to use it in a Form, and since I can't get the QueryBuilder syntax correct I can't figure out a way to get the data to limit itself.

How do you do a QueryBuilder or DQL statement when you have entities set up this way?

**EDIT**

Here's the SQL statement I'm trying to replicated, for reference:

```
SELECT S.* 
FROM store S 
JOIN store_county_xref SCX 
    ON SCX.store_id=S.id 
JOIN user_county_xref UCX 
    ON UCX.county_id=RCX.county_id 
WHERE UCX.user_id = 1
```

Part of the issue is I'm not sure what should be used. If I add mappedBy or inversedBy, Doctrine complains that the indexes don't exist (because it seems to be looking at the entity tables, not the JoinTable that is declared). I can't join a table like this because Doctrine complains that there is no association between the two entities:

```
SELECT s 
FROM AppStoreBundle:Store s 
JOIN AppUserBundle:County c WITH c.store = s.id
```

That makes sense because there is no 'store' member on the County, since it's things like Stores and Users are supposed to have counties, not the other way around, since County is just kind of tag.

I've even tried this, thinking it would work but didn't have much hope:

```
SELECT s 
FROM AppStoreBundle:Store s 
JOIN AppUserBundle:User u WITH u.counties = s.counties
```

I would switch to just using straight SQL instead of DQL/QueryBuilder, but I'm not sure how to run straight SQL inside of forms, which is a major drawback.

Comment: You should use the option mappedBy and inversedBy in your entities so there can be a owning side. Also, did you try any DQL syntax? Can you share some?

Comment: Updated the question with the SQL I'm trying to replicate, as well as some sample DQL I've tried

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example of the proper declaration in the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing)

I've excluded the other annotations on the code sample below

```
class County
{
    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="counties")
     **/
    protected $users;
 }

 class User
 {
      /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\County", inversedBy="users")
       * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_county_xref",
       *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
       *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="county_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
       * )
       */
      protected $counties;
 }
```

This would be the proper annotations and a proper query in an entity repository would be

```
 $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

 $queryBuilder->select(array('c', 'u'))
              ->leftJoin('c.users', 'u');

 return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

It should be exactly the same for the other entity.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, the County entity will need to have a member for every object that references it? So if I add a Market entity later on that has a County associated with it, I'll need to add an 'markets' member to the County entity?

Comment: Yes, that's how Doctrine figures out to join and hydrate associations between entities. Also, the value of `mappedBy` and `inversedBy` are the name of the member at the opposite side of the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Thomas Potaire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2155387/thomas-potaire). Good example ! Really helped me. See below my example queryBuilder. Where `string $search, int $locale` are.

```
$q  = $qb->select(array('a'))
                ->from(Article::class, 'a')
                ->leftJoin('a.locales', 'l')
                ->where(
                    $qb->expr()->like('a.articleName',"'%$search%'")
                )
                ->andWhere('l.id = '.$locale)
                ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC')
                ->getQuery();
            $articles= $q->getResult();

            if ($articles==null)
                throw new \Exception('Article with key '.$search.' not found');
```

The `Article` knows `Locale` within `$locales`. I have also ManyToMany relationship in my project: *article -> article_has_locale <- locale*